# python unittest discover

Tags: python, unit-testing

I don't understand something, with the python unittest discover.
I made this project:

```
project/
    __init__.py
    src/
        __init__.py
        criteria.py
    tests/
        __init__.py
        criteria_test.py
```

And to be able to know if I loaded the test correctly I ensure myself to make it fail with the code below

```
# coding: utf-8
import unittest

class TestCriteria(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass
    def test_criteriaFailure(self):
        self.assertTrue(False)
```

When I do the command in the command-line, I'm at the file project (the root of my packages), I guess everything can be imported.

I tried:

```
python -m unittest discover
python -m unittest discover -s tests -p '*_test.py'
```

but it always return me this output:

```
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

Ok
```

I'd like to understand how to use this feature (I'm using python3.2.3) without having to download and install Nose.

Comment: Is there a solution to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there anything in your `tests/__init__.py` file?

I'm looking into the source of unittest (Python's all open source, and very readable -- you can do it too :) ), because I'm more familiar with the Django test runner, but it is likely that your `__init__.py` file should at least have a line that looks like this:

```
from criteria_test import *
```

Comment: Well, it did not help, but you gave me the idea of going explore how people did on their projects in github. I have found a solution, with the TestLoader... Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Is there a solution to this question?